# How to Resolve error 1001 while installing windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, setup-project

I am getting following error while installing windows service.

> Error 1001 . An Exception occurred during the commit phase of the installation. This exception will be ignored and installation will continue. However , the application might not function correctly after installation is complete --> Cannot start service ACSERVICE2 on Computer'.'.-->The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Any help is appreciated...

Code is :

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            AC_Main objMain = new AC_Main();
            td=new Thread(new ThreadStart(objMain.Main));
            td.IsBackground = true;
            td.Start();
            eLog.WriteEntry("Service Started at :" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        catch(System.Security.SecurityException exc)
        {

        }
    }


 protected override void OnStop()
        {
            td.Abort();
            eLog.WriteEntry("Service Stopped at :" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
```

Committed Method is :

```
private void ProjectInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        serviceController.ServiceName = "ACSERVICE2";
        ConnectionOptions coOptions = new ConnectionOptions();

        coOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;

        ManagementScope mgmtScope = new System.Management.ManagementScope(@"root\CIMV2", coOptions);

        mgmtScope.Connect();

        ManagementObject wmiService;

        wmiService = new ManagementObject("Win32_Service.Name='" + this.serviceController.ServiceName + "'");

        ManagementBaseObject InParam = wmiService.GetMethodParameters("Change");

        InParam["DesktopInteract"] = true;

        ManagementBaseObject OutParam = wmiService.InvokeMethod("Change", InParam, null);

        this.serviceController.Start();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should never catch an error and then ignore it.

That might be your problem. What happens if you add some logging to the catch block, something like this?

```
catch(System.Security.SecurityException exc)
{
    eLog.WriteEntry("SecurityException: " + exc.Message);
}
```

Comment: Dear user Thanks for your answer but I also tried like this:


catch(System.Security.SecurityException exc)
{
     MessageBox.Show("OnStart :"+exc.ToString());
}

Comment: I don't think MessageBox will work in a windows service. Calling MessageBox.Show() is probably causing another error. You need to log the original error to a text file or the Windows Event Log or something like that.

Comment: @MubbasherKhaliq in a service if you want to do some writing to the screen it's impossible However you could log it to a text file or a windows log entry which is quite easy to do and it would give you a better starting point to figure out what went wrong in the service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this happens if you didn't correctly uninstall the service you are trying to install again. I had the same problem a few days ago. I created new project, copied the same code and installed the service again from scratch. 
My problem was that